# How to fetch JSON from a website in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I  want to get the `16` as a number from this JSON inside my Flutter application:
[link to the Json code](http://motyar.info/webscrapemaster/api/?url=http://teertoday.com/&xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]#vws)

[image: JSON illustration]

Comment: here is the link    http://motyar.info/webscrapemaster/api/?url=http://teertoday.com/&xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]#vws

Comment: You could use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html to use `querySelector()` and similar to get patrs of the HTML document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to import async, http, and convert.

```
var response = await http.get("http://motyar.info/webscrapemaster/api/?url=http://teertoday.com/&xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]#vws");
var jsonResponse = json.decode(response);

var line = jsonResponse["text"].replaceAll(new RegExp(r"(\s\n)"), ""); //this gives you the line of "text" and then replaces all of the spaces and \n
```

Comment: I am finding difficulty to implement the code can you make a  code to show the number at the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with flutter but i would read the value of the key "text" and then filter it with regex for digits.